# Reusable HTML bits in ASP.NET Core 3.1 marked red in editor

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a problem with the editor in Visual Studio when editing Razor Views.
I am using ASP.NET Core version 3.1.
I have the same HTML that is repeated several places, so I would like to make a function to do it.
This article describes how it should be done: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/344/what-happened-to-helpers-in-asp-net-core

So I have the following code in my .cshtml file:

```
@model WebApplication2.Models.RapportData
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, AuthoringTagHelpers
<h1>Report for @Model.PersonID</h1>
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h2>Section 1</h2>
            @{ MakeDiv(
                "Some div",
                new[]
                {
                       "QID1",
                       "QID2",
                       "QID3"
                }, "float:left"); }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
@{
    void MakeDiv(string subtitle, string[] props, string style)
    {
        <div style="@style">
            <h3>@subtitle</h3>
            <table>
                @foreach (var e in Model.Egenskaper
                   .Where(e => props.Contains(e.QId)))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="http://#@e.QId">@e.Name</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @e.Value
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

So the problem is that in Visual Studio 2019, version 16.7.6, the HTML-tags inside the @{ ... } function are marked as errors, but when running the code it works as it should. If I put a @ in front of the first DIV-tag, it seems the editor is happy, but then it won't compile.

So what am I doing wrong? How can I make Visual Studio uncderstand that it's not an error to have HTML tags inside the function?

This is how it looks like:

[image]

Comment: I have checked your code on my machine (using the same version of VS and the Asp.net core 3.1), everything works well, the screenshot [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUMVz.png), try to re-open the solution or create a new application to check whether the issue disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found a fix. It is to put in a statement that is terminated by semicolon at the top of the function:

```
@{
    void MakeDiv(string subtitle, string[] props, string style)
    {
        var a = 1; //this would fix it
        <div style="@style">
            <h3>@subtitle</h3>
            <table>
                @foreach (var e in Model.Egenskaper
                   .Where(e => props.Contains(e.QId)))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="http://#@e.QId">@e.Name</a>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @e.Value
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>};
    }
}
```

But I guess checking if there are any props to show would make more sense. As long as the first statement in the function is not HTML, but code that is terminated by semicolon.
I am still not sure why this happens. Maybe it's because of some plugin (I am using Resharper for instance).